# Ios Custom apps and Mdm

Tags: ios, mdm, apple-business-manager

I have a custom app on the app store.  I will assign it to a clients apple business manager account.  Does that client have the ability to be able to send configuration changes (for instance if they want to change a url that the app is connecting to) through their existing mdm to my custom app? Would there be any other setup I would have to do in my custom app besides reading the IOS userdefaults that the mdm server sets? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is outside the scope of Stack Overflow (see [ask]). Various ways to do this... have the MDM write to user-defaults... or to a data file... or have a "get the config url" url... that is, a url that never changes but returns the url to the "new" config...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the client's MDM supports [AppConfig](https://www.appconfig.org/ios/) then it can supply an XML file that contains specific settings. The contents of this XML file are merged with `UserDefaults` for your app on the device and your app can access them at runtime.

You need to create the logic in your app so that it uses these values when present and standard values if they are not.